# animatedFloatAsState hold different value than updated target value jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

I am trying to animate the float value using **animateFloatAsState** but while I am updating the **target** value the animated value gives me random different value .

For eg:

This is the animatedValue :

```
val animatedOffsetValue by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value
    )
```

This is target value which is being updated over time :

```
    val titleBarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
```

So when I updated the value as titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value = "new value"
And I check the value of animatedOffsetValue , it gives different than titleBarOffsetHeightPx.

full code :

```
package com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.history.presentation

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloatAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollSource
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Velocity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.business.util.DateConverter
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.business.util.Extensions.isScrolledToTheEnd
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.core.presentation.navigation.Screen
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.core.util.SnackbarController
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.history.presentation.components.DayGoalList
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.history.presentation.components.HistoryTitleBar
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.home.presentation.components.CustomNavBar
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.home.presentation.components.ITEM_WIDTH
import com.example.productivitytrackergoalscheduler.features.home.presentation.util.NavItems
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.math.roundToInt


const val NAV_BAR_HEIGHT = ITEM_WIDTH + 110


@Composable
fun HistoryScreen(
    ...
) {


    /** Height of title bar in dp */
    val titleBarHeight = 66.dp

    /** Height of title bar converted into float for offset */
    val titleBarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { titleBarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }

    /** Offset value of title bar. How much to move up or down */
    val titleBarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    /** Is the scrolling is up or down */
    val  isUpScrolled = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val animatedOffsetValue by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value
    )


    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object: NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                isUpScrolled.value = available.y < 0
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
                titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-titleBarHeightPx, 0f)


                Log.d("TAG", "onPostFling: animated ${animatedOffsetValue}")
                Log.d("TAG", "onPostFling: no animated ${titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value}")

                return Offset.Zero
            }

            override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {

                val scrolledTo  = if(isUpScrolled.value) titleBarHeightPx/3 else titleBarHeightPx/2

                if(-titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value < scrolledTo)
                {
                    titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value = 0f
                }else{
                    titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value = -titleBarHeightPx
                }

                return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
            }
        }
    }

    val endOfScrollList by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            scrollState.isScrolledToTheEnd()
        }
    }

    


    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
            ) {

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                         /** this offset id for while title bar hides or shows
                          *  The lazyColumn content also should move towards the
                          *  up and down as to fill empty space */
                        .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = animatedOffsetValue.roundToInt()) }
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                ) {
                    LazyColumn(
                        state = scrollState,
                        /** This modifier offset gives the space for title bar */
                        modifier = Modifier.offset{ IntOffset(x = 0, y = titleBarHeightPx.toInt())}
                    ){

                      ...
                    }
                }
            }

            /** Title Bar with z-index top */
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = titleBarOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) }
            ) {
                HistoryTitleBar(navController = navController)
            }
            /** end title bar*/

           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I edit with full code example

Comment: your code has a lot of unknown classes, such as `HistoryViewModel`, `SnackbarController`, etc. Please remove as much unrelated code as possible so it can be run in a blank project.